# Converting longitude and latitude data from JSON for Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, google-maps-api-3

I've been attempting to dynamically generate a Polyline on an embedded map via Google Maps API based on some data through JSON.

The example Google has given for a static set of coordinates to be passed to their API is:

```
    var flightPlanCoordinates_static = [
      {lat: 51.470544, lng: -2.588658},
      {lat: 51.867286, lng: -2.238049},
      {lat: 52.531292, lng: -1.899454}
    ];
```

However, I want to dynamically change the coordinates, so created the following Javascript code to read the JSON and, I'd hope, convert it into the correct format of the array to work with the API. However, something must be wrong because the dynamic list doesn't display the line on the map.

```
    var flightPlanCoordinates_dynamic = [];
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            for (var i = 0; i < myObj.lat.length; i++) {
                flightPlanCoordinates_dynamic[i] = {'lat' : myObj.lat[i], 'lng' : myObj.lng[i]};
            }

        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "myJSONfile.py", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

My JSON output looks like this (and is read by the Javascript without error):

```
{"lng": [-2.588658, -2.238049, -1.899454], "lat": [51.470544, 51.867286, 52.531292]}
```

If I print both variables to the console, I get similar results but it's clearly different enough for the API to ignore (no error) my dynamically generated content.

[Screenshot of the Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwiUK.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Posting entire code, without body HTML tags, in its non-working form:

```
<style>
  #map {
    height: 70%;
    width: 95%;
  }
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var flightPlanCoordinates_dynamic = [];
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            for (var i = 0; i < myObj.lat.length; i++) {
                flightPlanCoordinates_dynamic[i] = {'lat' : myObj.lat[i], 'lng' : myObj.lng[i]};
            }

        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "myJSONfile.py", true); //returns {"lng": [-2.588658, -2.238049, -1.899454], "lat": [51.470544, 51.867286, 52.531292]}
    xmlhttp.send();

    console.log(flightPlanCoordinates_dynamic)

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {51.470544, lng: -2.588658},
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    });

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates_dynamic,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 3
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
  }

</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDHO9uwpYA-dE57UXC4DWkp52eKDamZBEw&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: How/where/when are you adding the polyline to the map?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Looks like Google's sample is an array of objects where your json output is an object of arrays

Comment: The posted code "works": [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dLteatLw/).  Perhaps you aren't accounting for the asynchronous nature of `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: @geocodezip my bad, sorry. I've edited and provided a complete script.

Comment: With the updated code I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` because there is no element with id="test".

Comment: You have a typo in your map definition: `center: 51.470544, lng: -2.588658,` should be `center: {lat: 51.470544, lng: -2.588658},`

Comment: Thanks @KevinR. I'm not sure how I didn't spot that.

Comment: @geocodezip - thanks for both bits of advice. Corrected the map definition and followed Kevin's advice. Only remaining problem is storing the contents of the array after closing the {XMLHttpRequest} - I'll  have a play.

Comment: You either need to set `async` to false in the `xmlhttp.open()` call or account for its asynchronous behavior (create the polyline in the callback function).

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you so much - I've got it working now

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, it looks like the issue here is that Google is expecting an array of objects:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates_static = [
  {lat: 51.470544, lng: -2.588658},
  {lat: 51.867286, lng: -2.238049},
  {lat: 52.531292, lng: -1.899454}
];
```

but is being provided an object of arrays:

```
{"lng": [-2.588658, -2.238049, -1.899454], "lat": [51.470544, 51.867286, 52.531292]}
```

Comment: `flightPlanCoordinates_dynamic` is in the correct format, it is just the JSON data that is different and it isn't being used for the polyline.